# SSL connection error to mysql

Tags: macos, mysql, ssl, openssl

Since a couple days I cannot connect to several mysql instances when using SSL. I am quite sure it's a problem on my machine, since colleagues and production servers don't have this issue. In both my Python clients and the `mysql` command line client I get an error.

See this example when using the `mysql` CLI:

```
$ mysql -h blablabla.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -D dbname -U username
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

I think there is something wrong with my SSL settings, openssl, certificates, ... Well as you can guess from the options, I don't understand enough about this to pinpoint the problem :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps someone has updated the ssl libs. I'm sure, recently, some of the older, less secure protocols have been removed/disabled. You just need to ensure that both sides support a similar range.

Comment: Yeah, I also saw some info elsewhere one the minimum supported protocol version, maybe the server wants to use something my client doesn't accept (or vice-versa). I just don't know how I can check this (I don't even know what config I have locally, I know I have openssl installed, but I believe that's not used by default)